# Files listed by bash but unaccessible

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, filesystems, file-permissions

What would cause the following behavior on an Ubuntu 12.04 system?

1. I've SSHed into a machine as the "ubuntu" user.
2. Running `ls -lah /data/*` shows dozens of non-empty files (e.g. file1.txt, file2.txt, etc), all owned by the "ubuntu" user/group, and with full read/write access.
3. If I try to `cat /data/file1.txt`, bash gives me the error "cat: /data/file1.txt: No such file or directory"

In short, `ls` is listing files, but in every other way, the files essentially don't exist. I can't cat them or read them in any way. Even giving all the files 777 permission doesn't change anything. This is really bizarre. What's going on here?

Comment: What's the output of `ls -lad /data/file1.txt`? Is `/data/file1.txt` a symbolic link?

Comment: What permissions are set on the `/data` folder (`ls -lad /data`)? Maybe it has not `x` for the owner, so you can list files but cannot access them.

Comment: @NuTTy: If that were the problem, it wouldn’t be possible to see the file sizes, ownership, and permissions with `ls -l…`.

Comment: At the risk of insulting your intelligence – are you sure you are looking at files in `/data`? Because `ls /data/*` (without the `-d` option) will list the *contents* of any directories in `/data`. If all you want to do is list the contents of `/data`, it’s quite good enough to say `ls -lh /data` (or whatever options you want; and, of course, `-a` and `-A` will include things whose names begin with `.`). … … … … Also, please try `ls -lb /data` to check for non-displayable binary characters in filenames.

Comment: What is the result of

`file /data/file1.txt`

or `cd /date`

`file file1.txt`

Answer (score 2):

They might have binary characters in the filename.

For `cat /data/file1.txt`, try instead matching part of the name, and letting the shell figure out the rest of it:

```
cat /data/*1.txt
```

Comment: No, I already checked for this. Even trying to auto-complete in the directory doesn't return anything, because no files can be read.

Comment: Auto-complete will only "see" certain files.  Try this: `egrep . /data/*`

Answer (score 0):

The files might have been deleted, but are still open in an application. The files don't exist on disk, but because the application still has them "open", the kernel can't remove them from the filesystem quite yet.

Find the process using the files with

```
sudo lsof | grep data/file1.txt
```

And then try restarting/killing that application if it's not critical, or try rebooting the system.

Comment: There's no "application" being used. They were created with `rsync -avz /data ubuntu@remotehost:/data` run from my localhost. And bash still lists them with a filesize, some in the hundreds of MB.